# PHP extract value from onclick function

Tags: php

In my code I am trying to extract exact value from href's onclick I searched for various post but didn't succeed, I found a solution to follow but after trying it several times I making a mess for me

Here is my example download string

```
<a href="#" onclick="download_file('tokenid','n','hashname')">Get Name</a>
```

My requirement is to extract only values in this format so i can use explode function to seprate

```
tokenid,n,hashname
```

Currently My PHP Code is like this

```
$onclickAttr = $printtable;
if( preg_match("~download_file\('\K[^']++~", $onclickAttr, $match) )
$result[] = $match[0];
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Where are all those details from? Can you not just pass them to PHP using `$_GET` or AJAX?

Comment: @Script47 He is literaly parsing html content in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are using `preg_match` and `str_replace` to achieve desired output.

> **Regex:** `download_file\(\K[^)]+`
>
> **1.** `download_file\(\K` this will match `download_file(` and `\K` will reset the current match.
>
> **2.** `[^)]+` this will match all except `)`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/860736)

```
preg_match("#download_file\(\K[^)]+#", $string, $matches);
echo str_replace("'", "", $matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your regexp. Your expression has to match everything between parenthesis. Also the first element in the preg_match response is always the input string so use the correct index to retrieve the actual match (in my solution is 1).

Try to modify that like bellow.

```
 preg_match('/download_file\(([^\)]+)\)/', $onclickAttr, $match);
 $result[] = $match[1];
 var_dump($result);
```

Comment: works a bit but it still showing `download_file(`value`,`value`,`value`)` instead of `value,value,value`

Comment: @Rtra did you use $match[0] or $match[1] as I wrote above?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax to send the value to your php script

Answer (score 0):

```
you can get all **argument in array** can do any operation on array element

function download_file (){
        var htmlOutput = [];
        for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            htmlOutput.push( arguments[i]);
        }
        console.log(htmlOutput);
    }
```